# Finding my commits after pulling new master

Tags: git

I'm working on a project with some other guys and I want to pull the changes they pushed to master, and then rebase my branch (the newest commit of my branch let's say) on top of the new master. I'm not sure if this is the right way to go, but anyway I did the following steps. Here the starting point is my branch.

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git pull`
3. `git checkout <my-branch>`
4. `git rebase master`

This works but I have one doubt. When I pulled the new master, HEAD is at the new master's last commit. So running `git log --graph --decorate` doesn't show my branch. How do I see the commits on my branch at this stage (between 2 and 3)?

Comment: This actually looks correct if what you were trying to do is to rebase `my-branch` on the latest `master`.  Are you aware that what you did will have _no_ effect on `master`, but instead will rewrite the history of your local `my-branch` branch?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes of course, none of my commits has been pushed to master yet, what I want is just MASTER --> <newest-commit-on-my-branch>, and I did that with these 4 steps correctly. I'm just asking between step 2 and 3, how do I see my commits in git log? I did it with autocompleting the name of my branch, but what if I forgot the branch name?

Comment: Check out the answer by @barnes53 as it seems to be what you are really looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I pulled the new master, HEAD is at the new master's last commit. So running git log --graph --decorate doesn't show my branch. How do I see the commits on my branch at this stage (between 2 and 3)?

`git log` by default shows you the log of the current HEAD. Since at this point in your process you've checkout out the branch 'master' it will show you master's history. To see the history of another branch, such as your 'my-branch', you simply have to specify that:

```
git log --graph --decorate my-branch
```

You can also specify more than one branch at a time:

```
git log --graph --decorate master my-branch
```

---

> I did it with autocompleting the name of my branch, but what if I forgot the branch name?

You can list your branches to remind yourself of the name (`git branch --list`), or you can check the reflog:

```
git reflog
```

Which will show you this 'history' of (by default) HEAD. The output is something like:

```
6573269 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from foo to master
037f764 HEAD@{1}: commit: add baz
6573269 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to foo
```

As you can see, it will tell you the name of the branches you've switched between.

---

Depending on how git was installed you may have a handy tool for visuallyzing branches and browsing the history: `gitk`. Run the command `gitk --all &` and you'll get a GUI program that shows the history graph of all the branches along with a UI for browsing the contents of the commits.

Also, if you modify your `git log` command with the `--format=oneline` flag, you can get a more compact view than the usual multi-line format.

```
git log --graph --decorate --format=oneline
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Wonderful answer, thanks!!